Amplify Flutter "handleWebUISignInResponse is not supported" error after Google Sign In
Error java.lang.IllegalStateException: handleWebUISignInResponse is not supported is thrown after a successful Google login to my Amplify app using the AmplifyAuthCognito web view. This causes the app to crash straight after the successful login and the next activity is not shown.
I think my AWS services have been setup correctly since the login works.
I have all the necessary additions in the AndroidManifest.xml file:
        <activity
            android:name="com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.activities.HostedUIRedirectActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="myapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
...
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>

and pubspec.yaml:
  amplify_flutter: ^2.2.0
  amplify_auth_cognito: ^2.2.0
  amplify_authenticator: ^2.1.0
  amplify_api: ^2.2.0
  amplify_datastore: ^2.2.1
  amplify_analytics_pinpoint: ^2.2.0

main.dart:
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<void> _configureAmplify() async {
    if (!Amplify.isConfigured) {
      try {
        await Amplify.addPlugins([AmplifyAuthCognito(),
          AmplifyDataStore(modelProvider: ModelProvider.instance),
          AmplifyAPI()]);
        await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
        safePrint("Initialized Amplify.");
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        safePrint('An error occurred configuring Amplify: $e');
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _configureAmplify();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const AuthenticatorWithOnboarding();
  }
}

authenticator_with_onboarding.dart:
class AuthenticatorWithOnboarding extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthenticatorWithOnboarding({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Authenticator(
      // Sets the initial step to "onboarding" to display the onboarding
      // screen on app launch
      initialStep: AuthenticatorStep.onboarding,

      // If a builder method is provided the authenticator will
      // use this to build the authenticator based on the current state.
      //
      // This example only customizes the onboarding step. All other steps
      // will fallback to the prebuilt authenticator
      authenticatorBuilder: (context, state) {
        switch (state.currentStep) {
          case AuthenticatorStep.onboarding:
            return OnboardingView(
              navigateToSignIn: () => state.changeStep(
                AuthenticatorStep.signIn,
              ),
              navigateToSignUp: () => state.changeStep(
                AuthenticatorStep.signUp,
              ),
            );
          default:
          // returning null will default to the prebuilt authenticator for
          // all steps other than onboarding
            return null;
        }
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.light(useMaterial3: true),
        darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(useMaterial3: true),
        themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        builder: Authenticator.builder(),
        initialRoute: '/routeA',
        routes: {
          '/routeA': (BuildContext context) => const ChartsDemo(),
          '/routeB': (BuildContext context) => const FeaturesDemo(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

// An onboarding widget to display to unauthenticated users on initial app launch
class OnboardingView extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnboardingView({
    super.key,
    required this.navigateToSignIn,
    required this.navigateToSignUp,
  });

  final void Function() navigateToSignIn;
  final void Function() navigateToSignUp;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            const FlutterLogo(size: 200),
            const SizedBox(height: 32),
            Text(
              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. '
                  'Pellentesque faucibus viverra vehicula. In iaculis augue non '
                  'lacinia imperdiet. Aenean tempor mi nec condimentum posuere.',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: navigateToSignUp,
                child: const Text('Get Started'),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: navigateToSignIn,
                child: const Text('Sign In'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Error log:
E/AndroidRuntime(15233): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: handleWebUISignInResponse is not supported
E/AndroidRuntime(15233):    at com.amazonaws.amplify.amplify_datastore.NativeAuthPluginWrapper.unsupported(NativeAuthPluginWrapper.kt:415)
E/AndroidRuntime(15233):    at com.amazonaws.amplify.amplify_datastore.NativeAuthPluginWrapper.handleWebUISignInResponse(NativeAuthPluginWrapper.kt:258)
E/AndroidRuntime(15233):    at com.amplifyframework.auth.AuthCategory.handleWebUISignInResponse(AuthCategory.java:196)
E/AndroidRuntime(15233):    at com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.activities.HostedUIRedirectActivity.onResume(HostedUIRedirectActivity.kt:41)
E/AndroidRuntime(15233):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1603)
E/AndroidRuntime(15233):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:9134)
E/AndroidRuntime(15233):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:5399)
E/AndroidRuntime(15233):    ... 13 more

So it somehow seems to be using this Activity: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/blob/main/packages/amplify_datastore/android/src/main/kotlin/com/amazonaws/amplify/amplify_datastore/NativeAuthPluginWrapper.kt
That activity does not implement handleWebUISignInResponse. What Activity should the app be using?
What could be the issue? Thanks.
